# How to import a special format as a dictionary in python?

Tags: python

I have the text files as below format in single line,

```
username:password;username1:password1;username2:password2;
```

etc.

What I have tried so far is

```
with open('list.txt') as f:
    d = dict(x.rstrip().split(None, 1) for x in f)
```

but I get an error saying that the length is 1 and 2 is required which indicates the file is not being as key:value.

Is there any way to fix this or should I just reformat the file in another way?

thanks for your answers.

What i got so far is:

```
    with open('tester.txt') as f:
    password_list = dict(x.strip(":").split(";", 1) for x in f)


for user, password in password_list.items():
    print(user + " - " + password)
```

the results comes out as username:password - username1:password1

what i need is to split username:password where key = user and value = password

Comment: You don't actually split the string based on semi-colon or colon. First you need to read the file in then split it on semi-colon and then split each semi colon chunk into key-value pairs by splitting on the colon.

Comment: You _could_ use various tools to reformat the file, converting each `;` to a newline char. But I suspect that's _not_ permitted for this exercise. You're supposed to read that line, and split it up properly with your Python code. Do you know how to split `"username:password;username1:password1;username2:password2"` into a list of 3 strings, splitting on the semicolons?

Answer (score 0):

Since variable f in this case is a file object and not a list, the first thing to do would be to get the lines from it. You could use the https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=readline#file.readlines* method for this.

Furthermore, I think I would use strip with the semicolon (";") parameter. This will provide you with a list of strings of "username:password", provided your entire file looks like this.

I think you will figure out what to do after that.

EDIT
* I auto assumed you use Python 2.7 for some reason. In version 3.X you might want to look at the "distutils.text_file" (https://docs.python.org/3.7/distutils/apiref.html?highlight=readlines#distutils.text_file.TextFile.readlines) class.

Comment: The file only has one line.

Comment: @PM2Ring Even if there's only one line, `for line in file` is still a fine way to go.

Comment: @Gigaflop If you like, although `file.read()` is simpler. My objection in the previous comment was to `.readlines`, which is kind of pointless here.

Answer (score 0):

1. Load the text of the file in Python with `open()` and `read()` as a string
2. Apply `split(;)` to that string to create a list like `[username:password, username1:password1, username2:password2]`
3. Do a dict comprehension where you apply `split(":")` to each item of the above list to split those pairs.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('list.txt', 'rt') as f:
    raw_data = f.readlines()[0]
list_data = raw_data.split(';')
user_dict = { x.split(':')[0]:x.split(':')[1] for x in list_data }
print(user_dict)
```

Dictionary comprehension is useful here.

One liner to pull all the info out of the text file. As requested. Hope your tutor is impressed. Ask him How it works and see what he says. Maybe update your question to include his response.

If you want me to explain, feel free to comment and I shall go into more detail.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're probably getting:

> ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #3 has length 1; 2 is required

is because the text line *ends with* a semicolon. Splitting it on semicolons then results in a list that contains some pairs, and an empty string:

```
>>> "username:password;username1:password1;username2:password2;".split(";")
['username:password', 'username1:password1', 'username2:password2', '']
```

Splitting the empty string on colons then results in a single empty string, rather than two strings.

---

To fix this, filter out the empty string. One example of doing this would be

```
[element for element in x.split(";") if element != ""]
```

In general, I recommend you do the work one step at a time and assign to intermediary variables.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
f = open('test.txt').read()    
data = f.split(";")    
d = {}    
for i in data:    
    if i:    
        value = i.split(":")    
        d.update({value[0]:value[1]})    

print d
```

Comment: How is the OP going to learn if you post a complete solution ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers. Noted. Thanks for highlighting.

Comment: BTW, it's better to post Python 3 code, unless the OP tags the question Python 2, or specifically asks for Python 2 code. Python 2 will reach its official End of Life in a little over a year, no one should be using it for new code. And people new to Python should _definitely_ be learning Python 3. They can learn Python 2 later if they really need it.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a simple (but long) answer. You need to get the *line* from the file, and then split it and the items resulting from the split:

```
results = {}
with open('file.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
      #Only one line, but that's fine
          entries = line.split(';')
          for entry in entries:
              if entry != '':
                  #The last item in entries will be blank, due to how split works in this example
                  user, password = entry.split(':')
                  results[user] = password
```

Comment: `pass` is a reserved word

Comment: How is the OP going to learn if you post a complete solution ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Fixed